# Cypress not finding DOM elements even though playground selector shows it

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cypress

I've added `data-cy` id's to specific DOM elements in my Next/react application.

Yet, when it proceeeds to the `cy.get(`) command it errors out with

```
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: [data-cy=button-buy], but never found it.
```

Surprisingly, I can still confirm the existence of these `data-cy`'s in my codebase when running tests with the playground selector tool in the Cypress browser, they appear on the respective page.

When I `visit()` these pages I don't receive any error codes, so it should be that the test is authorized to visit these pages. SO why aren't the tests able to access these specific DOM elements?

Comment: Please add the structure of the DOM element.

Comment: Can you post the code of your Cypress test?

Comment: Yes, but I think it's authorization issue, I'm getting 401 errors. I can't access the url in the GET request. The thing that I'm confused about is that my login command seems to be working from before. And it also seems that I can visit the page. I just cant GET the payload from the server since I'm unauthorized.

 ```cy.login(EMAIL, PASSWORD).visit(`http://localhost:3000/properties/8418893f-c5a7-491a-83b4-a6a3b1980565`).get('[data-cy=button-buy]')```